# How external users can access the SharePoint application in case the SharePoint is connected to our company active directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, publishing-site, active-directory, authentication

I have created a Publishing Web application and I have specified that SharePoint is connected to our company Active Directory. Now all our employees are able to login to the SharePoint publishing site within our intranet without any problems. 
But two additional questions just rose in my mind which I cannot figure out:-

1. Let say an employee login to the SharePoint website from him home using his PC ? Will he be able and how he will be able to login to the SharePoint web application?
2. Regarding external customers. I was thinking that we can create new active directory account for each external customer. But this was refused by our system administrator. 
   So since the SharePoint is connected to AD, so how I can allow external customer (who are not inside our active directory) to login to our SharePoint Publishing site and see cerain pages inside it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

1. If your Publishing Web Application is available on internet, any employee can use their AD credentials to login to the system from anywhere.
2. For external customer, you can implement form based authentication. This is simply storing your external customers in an sql server database other than AD and get it working with SharePoint. Here is a good series of articles to do so:

http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the valuable link. So you mean i will have my SharePoint authentication being managed on two different places. Either on the AD or in the SQL database I will create. So this might not be clear on how SharePoint is going to choose where the user is being managed. On the AD if internal employee or on the SQL database if he is an external customer ?.

Comment: After configuring Form Based Authentication, SharePoint will handle it properly. Lots of companies are using this kind of solutions to manage their customers or external partners easily by this method.

Comment: i have added the "SharePoint 2013 FBA Pack" and now a login page with a drop down to select the login type will appear. but i am facing this issue. if a form based user test tries to access the SharePoint inside the development virtual machine it will work, but if i try to access the SharePoint from my host machine will get the following error:- "The server could not sign you in. Make sure your user name and password are correct, and then try again."